# how to fix my function implementing interpolation

Tags: r, function, interpolation

I have tried to make an interpolation function like below

Lets assume the so and op are values like

```
so <- seq(1,10, by=1)
op <- seq(10,20, by=1)



  myopt <- function(so, op) {
  # here I make two empty 
  ff <- c() # creates an empty df
  rr <- c() # creates an empty df
  fff <- c()
  inter = round(so[1]); # interpolation
  sid = round(so[2]); # sideways movement
  # if the lenght ff is bigger than 0
  library(pracma)
  if (length(ff) > 0){
    # then the step is 
    step <- (length(ff)+ inter)/(length(rr))
    fff <- interp1(ff,seq(1,length(ff), by=step))
  }  
  if (length(fff) >= length(rr)){
    fff = fff[1:length(rr)]
  } else {
    if (length(fff) < length(rr)){
      diff = length(rr)-length(fff)
      fff = c(fff,ones(1,diff)*ff(length(ff)))
    }
  }
  if (length(fff) > 0){
    if (sid > 0){
      mysid = ones(1,sid)*fff(1)
      ffff = c(mysid, fff[1:(length(fff) - sid)]);
    } else {
      if (sid <= 0) {
        sid = abs(sid);
        mysid = ones(1,sid)*ff(length(ff));
        ffff = c(fff[(sid+1):length(fff)], mysid);
      }
    }
  }
  # normalizing and scaling
  rrs <- (Re(rr)/max(Re(rr)))   
  fffs <- (Re(ffff)/max(Re(ffff)))
  # evaluation by correlation coefficient 
  if ((norm(rrs-mean(rrs)))* (norm(ffs-meas(ffs)))==0) {
    cc <- -1e10 
  } else {
    cc =((rrs-mean(rrs))*t((ffs-meas(ffs))))/((norm(rrs-mean(rrs)))*(norm(fffs-mean(fffs))))
  }
  return(cc)
}
```

the error says

```
Error in myopt(sol, op) : could not find function "off"
```

however

- `fff` is not a function but inside an `if` statement; what is wrong?
- The code should not even go there because the **ff** is an empty data frame. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `fff` is not a function but inside an if statement; what is wrong?

There is a bug here. You should change this line:

```
fff = fff(1:length(rr))
```

to

```
fff = fff[1:length(rr)]
```

Watch out the way for subsetting. Brackets `()` signals functions.

> The code should not even go there because the `ff` is an empty data frame. Where is the problem?

First, `ff` is not an empty data frame, but an empty vector.

Second, the program will go to that line.

```
  if (length(ff) > 0){
    # then the step is 
    step <- (length(ff)+ inter)/(length(rr))
    fff <- interp1(ff,seq(1,length(ff), by=step))
  }
```

The above block is `if` statement for `length(ff) > 0`. The call `fff = fff[1:length(rr)]` is outside this block, but inside `if(length(fff) >= length(rr))`. This evaluation is `TRUE`, because `length(fff) = 0` and `length(rr) = 0`. If you really think the program should not reach this line, then your function has been incorrectly written.

---

**Your new problem:**

```
  ff <- c() # creates an empty df
  rr <- c() # creates an empty df
  fff <- c()  ## add this line
```

This part of code:

```
  if (length(ff) > 0){
    # then the step is 
    step <- (length(ff)+ inter)/(length(rr))
    fff <- interp1(ff,seq(1,length(ff), by=step))
  }
```

is conditional. If it is not run, then there is no `fff` variable defined. Then there will be trouble in the following:

```
if (length(fff) >= length(rr))
```

Comment: I am straggling with the same error when I amended the code, I don't see any problem with it and also I used the trace to track it but with no success, can you look at above and see if you can see why I get the error?

Comment: thanks man, the first part is interpolation and the second part is to move the data in side way, then it normalise and calculate the correlation coefficient between them. I am having hard time to do it :-)))

Answer (score 2):

Nik,

The error is on line 16. `fff = fff(1:length(rr))`.

Your code is calling fff as a function. I hope that helps point you to the error.

Try `trace(myopt(so,op))`

thus,

```
 fff = fff[1:length(rr)]
```

### Debugging R

Check out the following information on Debugging R this will hopefully be of use in future.

- RStudio Debugging

  - https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio
- R Inferno - Circle 8 Believing It Does as Intended

  - http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

### RStudio Debugging

Here is an example of how to debug in RStudio. Load the code, then in the `console` type `trace(myopt(so,op))`

now we see the error

```
> trace(myopt(so,op))
Error in myopt(so, op) : could not find function "fff"
Called from: myopt(so, op)
Browse[1]>
```

we make the change to the code...

```
fff = fff[1:length(rr)]
```

note that you have to reload the function, prior to running again, as the function definition has changed...

```
myopt <- function(so, op) {
+   # here I make two empty 
+   ff <- c() # creates an empty df
+   rr <- c() # creates an empty df
+   fff <-c()
+   inter = round(so[1]); # interpolation
+   sid = round(so[2]); # sideways movement
+   # if the lenght ff is bigger than 0
+   library(pracma)
+   if (length(ff) > 0){
+     # then the step is 
+     step <- (length(ff)+ inter)/(length(rr))
+     fff <- interp1(ff,seq(1,length(ff), by=step))
+   }  
+   if (length(fff) >= length(rr)){
+     fff = fff[1:length(rr)]
+   } else {
+     if (length(fff) < length(rr)){
+       diff = length(rr)-length(fff)
+       fff = c(fff,ones(1,diff) * ff(length(ff)))
+     }
+   }
+ }
> myopt(so, op)
>
```

[image]

Comment: @nik - No worries - happy to help.

Comment: I have the same problem when I amended the code, I updated the answer with entire code i wrote but I cannot trace the problem it just says Error in myopt(so, op) : object 'fff' not found

Comment: no no, that was only one part! o solved that one, if you look at above, you can see I posted the entire code, that is what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Try `fff[1:length(rr)]` instead of `fff(1:length(rr))` in `if else` statement.